# Can I validate formdata in a C# endpoint for string length, maximum int values, and regular expression matching?

Tags: c#, forms, validation, data-annotations

I'm trying to perform some server-side validations in C# on form data that is being posted to an endpoint using JavaScript.

I would like to restrict the lengths of some string properties, the range of some int properties, and the pattern of some properties using regex.

I tried posting to a C# endpoint using JavaScript FormData() (I believe I need to use this because I am attaching files as well).

I deserialize the form into a datamodel, which has data annotations such as StringLength (I tried maxlength as well), RegularExpression, and Range.

However, even when I post it with invalid values (for example, a name that is longer than 50 characters, or an age that is greater than 120), it deserializes the object and all of the code works as usual.

Does anyone know how I can validate these fields on the server, so that it will not allow forbidden inputs?

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Here is a simplified version of my JavaScript code, posting to the endpoint:

```
    const form = new FormData();
    const url = "example_url";
    const body = {
      Id: 47,
      Info: {
        FirstName: "First",
        LastName: "Last"
        age: 56
      }
    };

    form.append("form", JSON.stringify(body));

    form.append(file.name, file);

    const response = await axios.post(url, form, { withCredentials: true});
```

Here is a simplified version of the C# endpoint code:

```
    using System.Web.Http;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Web;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public class ExampleController : ApiController
    {
      public HttpResponseMessage Example()
      {
      MyDataModel dataModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDataModel>       (HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["form"]);
    //code does some things with this data
      }
   }
```

Here is a simplified version of the datamodel code:

````
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public class MyDataModel
    {
      public string Id {get; set;}
      public Info Info {get; set;}
    }

    public class Info
    {
      [StringLength(50)]
      public string FirstName {get; set;}

      [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z]*$")]
      public string LastName {get; set;}

      [Range(0, 120)]
      public int age {get; set;}
    }`
```
````

Comment: I suggest reading [the article on Model Validation on Microsoft's site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api).